# cypress request to authorise with front end that calls rest api to login

Tags: cypress

I am having a problem using cy.request to authorise. Looking at what is coming back after the request, body is empty.

I think this may be due to the setup I have so hopefully someone can tell me.

I have a frontend svelte app with a login screen. This calls the login rest api for a backend server and receives a token if the username / password is successful.

Now when I login manually via the browser - success.

When I use cypress to complete the screen - success.

The backend is on a server such as mint20 then calling cy.request on https://mint20:3000/users/login rest api directly - success.

The login screen is (for instance) localhost:5000 which is svelte running locally for dev. So if use cy.request localhost:5000/ , then it doesn't work and I get back an empty body rather than a list of data for the user.

So with the configuration above, is request just not going to work?

Comment: Could you please explain what happens in "When I use cypress to call the login rest api directly - success" - I would expect that to be using cy.request(), but you list that seperately.

Comment: Make the same request using postman, and check what is returned.

Comment: `cy.request()` is for sending API requests. I don't think it would be useful to use it with `localhost:5000` which serves your web page. It should give you back something, however, but it would be the HTML, not an auth token.

Comment: According to the docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/testing-your-app#Logging-in, once login has been tested, then subsequent tests should use request.
Have I misunderstood this? Which may be the cause of the problem (:>)
It is supposed to give back cookies / token too. Nevertheless, the html that returns has an empty body so something is not right.

Comment: There may be a complication with Svelte which is newer technology than Cypress. Do you have an example repo I could try?

Comment: Hi Fody,
both the backend (using loopback node) and frontend (using svelte) are on github. I can send you the names on the repos (each is under a different user - long story) but it will be an amount of work for you to set up each one. Are you OK with that?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: Just to add, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049398/writing-to-svelte-writable-store-value-from-cypress/73156372#73156372 for a fuller answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already know this, so apologies in advance if so.

Generally, to authorise the app without having to fill in the login screen you would use `cy.request()` against the backend API and receive the token in the response.

The token needs to be stored somewhere, either cookies, localstorage, or sessionstorage (or multiple places).

When you use `cy.request()` to obtain the token, you would need to store it in the same place as happens when the user logs in through the login form.

One more step that's useful is to add a `cy.session()` to cache the token, because by default Cypress tries to clear down everything between tests (to avoid cross-test contamination).

This is the general pattern.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('login', () => {
    cy.request(...)                 // call backend to get the token
      .then(response => {
        cy.setCookie('token', response.body.token)
      })
  })
})
```

What happens is each test runs the `beforeEach()` first, but only the first call does the actual request.

Subsequent calls, the `cy.session()` reinstates the token to wherever you stored during the first call.

Comment: Hi Cody, always assume I know nothing; you will probably be right. (:>) As I mentioned, I have used request to test the backend API and that works. But the docs say (at least as I understand them) that request can also be used against the html. Which leads me back to my original question. In the architecture of the app, will request work re the docs?

Comment: Under the section [Bypassing your UI](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/testing-your-app#Bypassing-your-UI) I see `cy.request('POST', '/login', {...})` which is the test mimicking what happens when the user presses the button on the login form. In that example, `baseUrl` is pre-pended to `/login` to give  `https://localhost:5000/users/login`, but above you so the login endpoint is `https://mint20:3000/users/login` so that's the URL you need to post username and password to. Essentially, whatever POST your login button sends is what your `cy.request()` should do.

Comment: OK. In which case I did misread what that might do. I already have that working then by going directly to the api of the backend server.
Many thanks for sticking with this.
Regards,John
(Sorry about the Cody rather than Fody - android autocorrect!)

Comment: Just to add. I think there may be a problem with request to login using the backend api and then subsequent html calls when using a single page application because having got the token via the api, then visiting via the UI (localhost:5000) will go to the login screen. That token is not being put in the browser.
In summary, using the UI via cypress works, doing only backend api calls works but a mixture does not. I think this is down to my design - it may not be cypress friendly.

Comment: Well, it looks to me like you need to explicitly store the token after obtaining it via `cy.request()`. The question is where - to find out, in a browser (not Cypress) perform a login via the screen, then go to "Application" menu in devtools and check if anything is added to Local Storage, Session Storage, or Cookies. (For example on the Stackoverflow page there are entries in Local Storage and Cookies). The corresponding action needs to happen in `cy.request(...).then(response => // store token here)`.

Comment: I think this may be where I am doing things incorrectly. Though the svelte app receives the token, it does not store the app in the browsers cookie, local or session storage. 
Within the code I store it in a writable svelte/store which is used by the application to add to api calls to the backend.
And because with request I am going directly to the backend, that does not get set.
So perhaps I should store the token in localstorage rather than writable as this is not going to change during a session?

Comment: Just had a quick look at writable store, I'd say `cy.session()` would not work with it. But do you really want to change the app architecture to accommodate a test mechanism i.e `cy.session()`? An alternative would be to expose the store on `window` (inside app) and let the test call `store.update((() => token)` after receiving it from `cy.request()`